# YouTube iframe API -- referencing Javascript object from inside onPlayerStateChange event handler

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

This is the working player in my HTML file. I want the handler for `YT.PlayerState.ENDED` a.k.a. `event.data == 0` to be able to reference a client-side Javascript object (`booth`) that stores videoIDs, but `booth` is undefined. What is the proper technique for doing something like this?

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == -1) {
    player.playVideo();
  }
  if (event.data == 0) {
    alert("This alert pops up");
    alert(window.booth);
    // Undefined -- even though "booth" is already instantiated in linked JS file

    /*
    window.booth.cue.index++;
    event.target.loadVideoById(window.booth.cue.list[booth.cue.index].id);
    */
  }
}
```

Here is the entire [Javascript file](http://pastebin.com/15Sp0YPY) -- line 16 `socket.on('boothCreated'...` is the handler where `booth` is instantiated and only after that is the player created -- so it would seem to me that the player should be able to reference this.

Comment: Can you provide the linked JS file? Browser is never wrong.

Comment: @Azamantes, I'm just tagging you in case you didn't notice I added the JS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need not look any further, the beginning of the linked JS file says everything:

```
window.onload = function () { // beginning of function closure
    var user = null; // these are private variables inside the function
    var booth = null; // these are private variables inside the function
    // etc...
```

If you want these variables to be visible from `window.booth` etc then you need to do this:

```
window.onload = function () { // beginning of function closure
    window.user = null; // these are now public
    window.booth = null; // these are now public
    // etc...
```

You just made them private and thus invisible from the 'outside world'.

Or if you want to use them while keeping them private, then you would need to somehow join the files and put your `onPlayerStateChange` function inside the `window.onload = function() { ...`.

Comment: Thank you -- you're awesome! I'm embarrassed I was unaware of such an elementary JS thing.

Comment: Don't worry, we've all been there :)